# Why i am not able to get output in Insertionsort Coded java

Tags: java, insertion-sort

I am unable to get the output while implementing InsertionSort

```
package app;

public class InsertionSortDemo {

    public static void  insertionsort1(int A[]) {
        int i,j,v;
        for(i=2;i<=A.length-1;i++) {
            v=A[i];
            j=i;
            while(A[j-1]>v && j>=1) {
                A[j]=A[j-1];
                j--;
            }
            A[j]=v;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String s[]) {
        int ar[]={6,8,1,4,5,3,7,2};
        insertionsort1(ar);
    }
}
```

Output Shown:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
>       at app.InsertionSortDemo.insertionsort1(InsertionSortDemo.java:11)
>       at app.InsertionSortDemo.main(InsertionSortDemo.java:23)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
while(A[j-1]>v && j>=1)
```

The conditions in Java are evaluated from left to right. So, when `j` has a value of `0`, you will access to `A[-1]`, thus causing the exception.

Just change the way you verify the `while` loop:

```
while(j>=1 && A[j-1]>v)
```